# Error when trying to map aesthetics with geom_signi

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a faceted boxplot with significance levels indicated as asterisks like '***'.
The problem is, I am getting an error when trying to add the geom_signif layer.

> `Warning message:`
> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, annotations, y_position, map_signif_level.

This is my data:

```
 veg_un <- structure(list(Datum = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2021-04-08", 
"2021-05-17", "2021-07-07"), class = "factor"), Soll = c("1192", 
"1192", "149", "2484", "552", "172", "1192", "1189", "2484", 
"552", "552", "552", "119", "1192", "2484", "1202", "149", "552", 
"1202", "1202"), Entfernung = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2", 
"5"), class = "factor"), DGUnkraut = c(0, 1.3, 0.3, 3.4, 0, 2.5, 
4, 0, 1, 0.9, 0, 0.8, 0.5, 3, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 4, 0.5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is my code so far.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)

anno_df <- compare_means(DGUnkraut ~ Entfernung, group.by = "Soll", data = veg_un, p.adjust.method = "holm") %>%
  mutate(y_pos = 7, p.adj = format.pval(p.adj, digits = 2))

ggplot(veg_un, aes(x=Entfernung, y=DGUnkraut)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge()) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Entfernung), position=position_jitterdodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(~Soll) + 
  theme_minimal()+
  ggsignif::geom_signif(
    inherit.aes = F,
    data=anno_df, 
    aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=p.adj, y_position=y_pos, map_signif_level = T),
    manual=TRUE)
```

I don't know why this is happening. Also, the p-values are way too high. I tried to modify this with y_position, but since I can't control the aesthetics, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try one of these

```
anno_df <- compare_means(DGUnkraut ~ Entfernung, group.by = "Soll", data = veg_un, p.adjust.method = "holm") %>%
  mutate(y.position = 7, p.adj = format.pval(p.adj, digits = 2))

p <- ggplot(veg_un, aes(x=Entfernung, y=DGUnkraut)) + 
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge()) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Entfernung), position=position_jitterdodge()) + 
  facet_wrap(~Soll) + 
  theme_minimal() 
  
p + ggsignif::geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("2", "5")), map_signif_level = T)
p + ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(anno_df, label = "p.adj")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several things.

1. Your p.adj is 1 all the time. So I can't create a label with *
2. Although you are receiving some warnings I am not receiving any error and the code is doing what I expected.
3. You can resize the ylim and define the height of the labels.

library(tidyverse)
library(ggsignif)
library(ggpubr)

```
  anno_df <- compare_means(DGUnkraut ~ Entfernung, group.by = "Soll", data = veg_un, p.adjust.method = "holm") %>%
    mutate(y_pos = 5, label = format.pval(p, digits = 2))
  
  ggplot(veg_un, aes(x=Entfernung, y=DGUnkraut)) + 
    geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge()) + ylim(0,7) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Entfernung), position=position_jitterdodge()) + 
    facet_wrap(~Soll) + 
    theme_minimal()+
    ggsignif::geom_signif(
      inherit.aes = F,
      data=anno_df, 
      aes(xmin=group1, xmax=group2, annotations=label, y_position=y_pos, map_signif_level = T),
      manual=TRUE)
```

I obtained this image. I hope is what you were looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  Regarding your points1. Yes, in this sample every p.adj = 1, but in my actual df there are also lower p values.
2. Thats what I dont get. I am getting the error mentioned above.
3. Yeah I cant do that, because ggplot somehow ignores my aes() call which also included y_position..

Comment: if you share the data you have, I could try to create the plot.

Comment: Is there a way to share my data directly with you? When I click on your profile I cant seem to DM you.. its a huge dataset so I just used slice_sample to create a small repex. Thanks!

Comment: you can go through my github account and write me there. I don't want to publish here my email.